# Why is "echo [#10]" equal to 1?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, centos

Can someone explain why these `echo` commands doesn't output `[#10]` and so on?

```
# echo [#10]
1
# echo [#11]
1
# echo [#12]
1 2
# echo [#13]
1
# echo [#14]
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a file named "1" and a file named "2" in your current directory.

The shell is performing pattern matching on the glob patterns *before* handing the results to `echo`. `[#10]` is a character class containing a <kbd>#</kbd>, a <kbd>1</kbd> and a <kbd>0</kbd>.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching

If you want the literal `[#10]`, etc, you have to enclose it in quotes, single or double doesn't matter.

Comment: +1 I believe that's the reason. But it can be file or directory or link named `1, 2`

Comment: That is correct. I have such files =) How would you then do the following?: `echo "Error: something wend wrong. Error code [#12]"`?

Comment: `echo "Error: something wend wrong. Error code [#12]"` will work as is since it is in the quotes OR else you can use: `echo 'Error: something wend wrong. Error code [#12]'`

Answer (score 2):

(to answer the question in your last comment)

You could use the [printf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) command:

```
 printf "Error: %s went wrong. Error code [#%d]\n" "something" $[10+2]
```

<sup>The `$[10+2]` is here to show how to do arithmetic in shell. You could replace `"something"` with e.g. `$somevariable` ...</sup>